# How to find out whether the user dismiss the credential action sheet or there is no credentials

Tags: webauthn, ios16, password-less, passkey

I want to implement passkey in my app. I am wondering if there is a robust way to distinguish between these two situations:
the user cancels the action sheet (ASAuthorizationController)
there are no credentials at all
Both situations give a canceled error. I noticed a localized string in NSError.userInfo explaining the reason in situation 2, but this is not a robust way of distinguishing between them because the behavior can change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The ASAuthorizationController API for passkeys is based around WebAuthn and WebAuthn [deliberately](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-assertion-privacy) does not distinguish these situations for privacy reasons. While the privacy considerations for a native app may be different, this is probably why ASAuthorizationController is making these failures (mostly) the same.

Answer (score 0):

These two cases are not meant to be distinguished programmatically.
For privacy reasons, and you're right that the userInfo shouldn't be relied upon. You likely want to either use AutoFill-assisted requests, or perform a modal request with a silent fallback (i.e. no UI gets displayed you get the cancel callback immediately if there are no credentials).
These options are displayed in detail in the [Meet passkeys developer session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10092/).
For simpler implementation I'd use [passkeys.com](https://passkeys.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. I even made a github [issue](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1749) about this problem because it's impossible to know if the user already has credentials or not... It's kind of a pain for user guidance IMHO.